# Check for duplicate values in multiple select dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I'm doing validation for multiple select dropdowns, which has been dynamically added.

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sL6ofchd/1/)

```
<select id="sel_1">
    <option value="one">one</option>
</select>

<select id="sel_2">
    <option value="two">two</option>
</select>

<select id="sel_3">
    <option value="one">one</option>
</select>

<select id="sel_4">
    <option value="three">three</option>
</select>
```

How do i validate if duplicate values are selected

Comment: you can delete the dulplicate select after generation

Comment: Please share with us your validation code as well. Also, JSFIDDLE link should be reproduce the issue that you are facing.

Comment: i;m looking for validation, Not the delete

Comment: updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/sL6ofchd/2/

Comment: @Matarishvan i suggest pls try something before asking

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you could code like this. onclick of save button call this.

```
function save() {
    var selects = document.getElementsByTagName('select');
    var values = [];
    for(i=0;i<selects.length;i++) {
        var select = selects[i];
        if(values.indexOf(select.value)>-1) {
            alert('duplicate exists'+select.value); break;
        }
        else 
            values.push(select.value);
    }
}
```

> how can this code prevent the user from submitting until the values are all unique? 
>   **ans:**

```
function save() {
        var selects = document.getElementsByTagName('select');
        var values = [];
        for(i=0;i<selects.length;i++) {
            var select = selects[i];
            if(values.indexOf(select.value)>-1) {
                alert('duplicate exists'+select.value); return; //if duplicates found we are returning. without save and no need to continue.
            }
        }
    //saveform here
    }
```

Comment: how can this code prevent the user from submitting until the values are all unique? I know this is kinda old, but I'm stuck with a similar problem. But so far this looks like the right direction.

Comment: @helloworld updated the answer. you can also do with some boolean values also